# Blender 2.9 - Skin modifier and displayed vertices

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

Anyone know how to stop edit mode from showing all of the vertices that the skin modifier is making? (example below)

[image]

Comment: can you please share your file? Because from this screenshot I am not even sure what am I looking at, how did you activate this?

Comment: It's gone now, so I can't share anything useful with you. I have no idea what I did. I'm going to keep trying to figure this out. Will update when I find something.
To achieve what's in the picture, just add a skin modifier and subdivision modifier to a single vertex and extrude that vertex.

Comment: this must be something in your settings because it doesn't happen to me

Comment: Here's a video of it happening.
https://gfycat.com/glaringlivejapanesebeetle
Sorry, it's tiny. gfycat is lame.